# Autoconf with ENV vars after a rebuild

Tags: configure, iperf

I am trying to get iperf3.2 to build using ENV vars for dirs like prefix.
This works fine on one machine when i run ./configure using paths like $MYDIR, etc...

The problem is after i run configure, and commit the files to my git.
When i clone to a diff machine (like jenkins) and run the build the autoconf decides to re build the makefiles but they have the old paths from the old machine and not the ENV vars.

How can i store/setup the configure call to preserve the $MYDIR and not expand that out so when it decides to rebuld the Makefiles somewhere else it uses the correct DIR based on ENVs?

Forgive my ignorance....

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
I was passing in the paths to configure using bash vars like so:

```
--prefix = "$MYDIR/foo"
```

which gets evaluated out to real path like /home/user/blah

changed it to this:

```
--prefix = '${MYDIR}/foo'
```

which gets placed exactly as displayed which is what i want/need.